# Logging the log messages from different packages into different files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Suppose I have these packages in my application - foo.bar and foo.foobar, And I want to send all log4j log messages that are coming from foo.bar package to foobar.log file and the log messages coming from foo.foobar to foofoobar.log file, how should I configure the log4j.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use appender-ref in the logger configuration:

```
<logger name="foo.bar">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
</logger>
```

Have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) for full examples.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest also to set additivty to "false" when you have overlapping hierarchies and don't want duplicate log messages.

i.e:

```
<logger name="foo.bar">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
</logger>
<logger name="foo.bar.xyz" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE2" />
</logger>
```

This way messages directed to FILE2 won't be written to FILE1

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out later and compiled the explanation into a blog post, which might help other people who are reading this page.

[How to send log messages to different log files](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-log-messages-to-different-log-files/)